# Create custom HTML/JS app inside page

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, forms

I'm trying to build a plugin that integrates somehow a custom tool (like a widget) that displays data from a database. Basically it's an HTML template with some custom JS code that uses AJAX to make backend requests.

I tried searching online but I still feel confused about which way is best, I was thinking about creating a custom shortcode that "expands" into the tool wherever it's placed (in a single page in this case), is that good?

Also is it possible to use buttons and text fields from the current WP theme by referring some specific CSS? Don't want to reinvent the wheel there.

Finally, I think it's possible to use the JQuery library, isn't it?

Thanks a lot